# C++ class constructor is called twice when new operator is overriden - why

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code to unsderstand the operator new

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;




class Dog {

public:
    Dog() {
        cout << "Dog constructed\n";
    }

    //overriding the new operator of the class and explicitely doing what it internally does
    void* operator new(size_t n) {
        cout << "operator new overriden in Dog class called size_t n = " << n << " Sizeof(Dog) = "<< sizeof(Dog) << endl;

        //Allocating the memory  by calling the global operator new 
        void* storage = ::operator new (n);

        // you can now create the Dog object at the allcated memory at the allocated memory

        ::new (storage) Dog(); //---------> Option 1 to construct the Dog object --> This says create the Dog at the address storage by calling the constructor Dog()

        return storage;
    }

    int m_Age = 5;
    int m_Color = 1;
};

void* operator new(std::size_t size)
{
    void* storage = malloc(size);
    std::cout << "Global operator new called - Asked for: " << size
        << ", at: " << storage << std::endl;
    return storage;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{



    cout << "calling new Dog" << endl;
    Dog* ptr = new Dog;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the output comes as below

================================================

calling new Dog

operator new overriden in Dog class called size_t n = 8 Sizeof(Dog) = 8

Global operator new called - Asked for: 8, at: 0xf15c20

Dog constructed

Dog constructed

==========================================

Any idea why the Dog object Dog's construcor is called twice ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are constructing a `Dog` in a function that should only **allocate space** for a `Dog`. The compiler then constructs a second `Dog` over that one.

Observe that the return type is `void*`, i.e. a pointer to unknown. If you were meant to construct a `Dog`, the return value would be `Dog*`

Answer (score 8):

It it because you construct a `Dog` object using placement new inside of overloaded operator new while allocating storage for Dog `object` being constructed:

```
::new (storage) Dog();
```

Operator new should never construct an object, it should only allocate memory and compiler will emit code to construct an object using the allocated memory.

Comment: You mean the placement allocation is calling ::new (storage) Dog(); in the overloaded new operator of the Dog class. so is it OK to have the new operator overriden as  void* operator new(size_t n) {void* storage = ::operator new (n); return storage;}

Comment: @3mr `::new (storage) Dog();` is a placement new which does not allocate anything and only constructs object using supplied storage. It should not be used inside of overloaded `operator new`

Comment: in the main method I tried void* pDog = operator new (sizeof(Dog)); new(pDog) Dog(); but the second line gives a compilation error and works when I have it as ::new(pDog) Dog(); what does this :: mean when it comes before the new key word. Please help

Comment: @3mr `::` is a name resolution operator. When it is used as leading part of qualified name then this name refers to a name in global namespace. That is `::new (storage) Dog();` invokes a global placement operator new (which is not overloaded).